# Kitchen Aid fridge/freezer dispenses 1 ounce of water when pressing ice

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, ice-maker

I have a Kitchen Aid refrigerator model #: KRSC503ESS00

I’m having a weird problem that occurs when I press the ice dispenser pad. Basically, the fridge dispenses 1 ounce of water out of the water spout and then dispenses ice. I have two young children so I’m not sure if they pressed the buttons and somehow got it into this state.

If I press the water dispenser pad for a second so that a little water comes out and then the ice dispenser it just dispenses ice.

I actually found a diagnostic video and it appears that the control board thinks both dispenser pads are pressed whenever you press either the ice or water one.

Anyone familiar with Kitchen Aid control boards?

Comment: Are there any instructions?

Comment: I actually found a diagnostic video and it appears that the control board thinks both dispenser pads are pressed whenever you press either the ice or water one. Not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by the ice door motor. When the ice lever is pressed, this causes the motor to open the ice door for about two seconds. While the motor is running, it sends noise back into the line that causes the water valve to open. Thus, while the motor is running to causes about 1 ounce of water to come out, but once the ice door is open and the motor stops, the water stops dispensing.

To test this, you can pop off the front control panel and disconnect the motor. Then press the ice lever and see if you still get a water leak. If you don't, then you know you need to replace the motor.

The motor part number is W10781990.